# how to completely change the style of a button CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, button

I am using CSS for the first time (in an AngularJS project) and I am a bit confused because I cannot apply a certain type of style to a `<button>` element.
This `<button>` element is fundamental in my project because I have to use `ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"` to obtain a form validation in AngularJS (This directive does not work when used with other elements, such as `<span>` or `<div>`). The result is the following:

```
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="$ctrl.myMethod()">LABEL</button>
```

My problem is that I cannot apply a CSS for this `<button>` element which totally eliminates the button outline and only returns a string. I would like a style like this for the button:
[Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EGD1.png)

Unfortunately I can only apply this style to `<span>` or `<div>` elements, which cannot be useful in this case for my project... How do I totally change the style of the button?

Comment: Add a `class` to that button, and then add the CSS styles for the class?

Comment: did you get your answer?